# In-App Purchase redirects to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am playing for couple days already with in-app purchases and found next issue (let me know if it expected behavior).

I have application on TestFlight at the moment, not in Apple Store.

I have a list of items that user may purchase and when user taps "Purchase" it goes through all normal steps: product is selected, then I show my `AlertViewController` with confirmation of purchase, and on completion of "submit" action of `AlertViewController` I call `buyProduct` in my `IAP Manager` . Then normal dialog about "Cancel / Buy" appears on dialog "Confirm Your In-App Purchase" with [Environment: Sandbox] etc.

However when I tap "Buy" I am redirected to the previous View Controller and "You're all set." is displayed on the previous View Controller, not the one I was at.

If it is OK for TestFlight version - then fine. If this is the behavior I will have at Apple Store then it is bad I need a fix. Here is my in-app purchase manager:

```
class IAPManager: NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = IAPManager()

static let IAPManagerPurchaseNotification = "IAPManagerPurchaseNotification"

fileprivate var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
fileprivate var productsRequestCompletionHandler: ProductsRequestCompletionHandler?

func initialize() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
}

func deinitialize() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
}

/// Request products from Apple Store.
/// - parameter products: IAPProduct to purchase.
func requestProduct(products: [IAPProduct], _ completionHandler: @escaping ProductsRequestCompletionHandler) {
    productsRequest?.cancel()
    productsRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler

    var productIdentifiers: Set<String> = Set<String>()
    for product in products {
        productIdentifiers.insert(product.rawValue)
    }

    productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
    productsRequest?.delegate = self
    productsRequest?.start()
}

/// Does actual purchasing against Apple Store.
/// - parameter product: product that user wants to purchase.
func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
    Log.info(message: "User \(UsersManager.sharedInstance.currentUserId) is purchasing \(product.productIdentifier)", sender: self)
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
}

class func canMakePayments() -> Bool {
    return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
}

/// Restores previously purchased non-consumable items.
func restorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
}

extension IAPManager: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    Log.info(message: "Loaded list of products...", sender: self)
    let products = response.products
    productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
    clearRequestAndHandler()

    for p in products {
        Log.info(message: "Found product: \(p.productIdentifier) \(p.localizedTitle) \(p.price.floatValue)", sender: self)
    }
}

func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    Log.error(message: "Failed to load list of products with error: \(error.localizedDescription)", sender: self)
    productsRequestCompletionHandler?(false, nil)
    clearRequestAndHandler()
}

private func clearRequestAndHandler() {
    productsRequest = nil
    productsRequestCompletionHandler = nil
}
}

extension IAPManager: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case .purchased: complete(transaction: transaction)
            case .failed: fail(transaction: transaction)
            case .restored: restore(transaction: transaction)
            case .deferred: Log.info(message: "Purchase is deffered", sender: self)
            case .purchasing: Log.info(message: "Purchase is in progress", sender: self)
        }
    }
}

private func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    Log.info(message: "Purchase is completed.", sender: self)
    deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}

private func restore(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else {
        return
    }

    Log.info(message: "Purchase \(productIdentifier) is in restore state.", sender: self)
    deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: productIdentifier)

    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}

private func fail(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    Log.info(message: "Purchase is failed.", sender: self)
    if let transactionError = transaction.error as NSError? {
        if transactionError.code != SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
            Log.error(message: "Transaction Error: \(transactionError.localizedDescription)", sender: self)
        }
    }

    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}

private func deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: String?) {
    guard let identifier = identifier else {
        return
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPManager.IAPManagerPurchaseNotification), object: identifier)
}
}
```

Code that calls IAPManager:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "<Title>", message: "<Message>", preferredStyle: .alert)
IAPManager.sharedInstance.requestProduct(products: [product]) { success, products in
        guard success, let products = products, !products.isEmpty else {
            Log.error(message: "Error occured during product request.", sender: self)
            return
        }

        let product = products[0]

        let submit = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { action in                
            IAPManager.sharedInstance.buyProduct(product)
        }

        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .destructive, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(submit)
        alert.addAction(cancel)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: this is not a usual behaviour @Array , check your alert function is their any code written which navigate you back

Comment: No, I updated with code calling to in-app purchase manager

Comment: Btw, issue disappeared on its own. Maybe this was caused by other factors.

Answer (score 0):

Issue disappeared on its own. I was fixing multithreading and probably that's was the cause. I cannot reproduce right now, but if I will find the real cause - I'll post it here. Thanks all.